# Parameter substitution in input redirection

Tags: shell, redirect, input, parameters, substitution

I'm a newbie to shell scripting and I have the following problem:

If I enter into the shell

```
cat << EOF
'"$10^2$"'
EOF
```

I expected (and wanted) to get something like

```
"$10^2$"
```

but actually it used parameter substitution and I got

```
'"0^2"'
```

Why does it parameter substitution (I used single quotes!?)? And how can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the dollar sign:

```
cat << EOF
'"\$10^2$"'
EOF
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
"$10^2$"
```

Otherwise `$1` is being expanded by shell and shows output as empty string only only and you get output as `'"0^2$"'`

**UPDATE:** Otherwise use this form of heredoc to avoid variable expansion:

```
cat <<'EOF'
'"$10^2$"'
EOF
'"$10^2$"'
```

**Explanation:** As per man bash:

```
<<[-]word
    here-document
delimiter
```

No  parameter  expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word.  If any characters in word are quoted, the
       delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.  **`If word is unquoted, all lines of the  here-document
       are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.`**  In the latter case, the character sequence \ is ignored, and
       \ must be used to quote the characters \, $, and `.

See bolded text above for the explanation why variables got expanded in your example but not when I used quoted `'EOF'`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Why is it expanded, although I put the expression in single quotes?

Comment: Okay, this sounds good :) so although I put the expression in **single** quotes bash interprets the string? I had expected that it gets interpreted when I put it in double quotes, and gets not interpreted when I put it in single quotes...

Comment: Yes difference is because of my use of `'EOF'`

Comment: I mean also in the here-document without quoting the 'EOF' I expected that parts in single quotes do not get evaluated (because they are in single quotes), but obviously they get evaluated...

Comment: If you use `cat << EOF` without quotes shell will expand the here-document without looking at your single/double quotes. In face these quotes loose their special meaning in here-doc if word is unquoted as in your question.